# delphi : move between cells of string grid

Tags: delphi, tab-ordering

How can I move between cells of a string grid in Delphi by tab or arrow keys? As you know, a string grid in delphi has only one tab order but I need to move between cells by arrow keys or tab to be more comfortable and user friendly .

I tried to use a KeyPress event, but this event only knows chars and doesn't know control keys like tab and ...

Comment: About the error: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
StringGrid.Options := StringGrid.Options + [goEditing, goTabs];
```

Or set this designtime.

Now you can move from cell to cell with tab and arrow keys. If you are actually editing a cell, then you have to release the focus first if you want to move to the cell to the left or right. In that case, use (shift) tab.

Comment: goediting is for type to cells ,,, if its false u cant type in cells

Answer (score 0):

```
{ This handles arrow left and right in the GRID
}
procedure TJournalForm.JournalGridKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);

begin
    if (JournalGrid.EditorMode = True) then      //  if arrowing while editing…
      begin
           if Key=VK_Left then if JournalGrid.Col>(JournalGrid.FixedCols+1) then JournalGrid.Col:=JournalGrid.Col-1;
         if Key=VK_Right then if JournalGrid.Col<(JournalGrid.ColCount-1) then JournalGrid.Col:=JournalGrid.Col+1;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Set `EditorMode := false` before setting a new value to the `Col` property.